# What is the correct way to return a value from a callback function in an async lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I am using a client that only supports the callback signature so, I wanted to make sure i am using the best practice while returning values from a callback function. I am currently wrapping it in a promise and returning the promise to the lambda runtime. Below is the function code/format that i have.

```
const client = new SomeClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.get(function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(response);
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

I know i could use a synchronous lambda function and wait for the response before returning. But that would take more execution time and incur more fees in AWS lambda.

Comment: 1) In your try block you return a promise, if you want the catch to trigger you need to await on this promise. As written it could only trigger if there was an error in formation of the promise not its rejection.

Comment: 2) You're catching an error to return it. It's unlikely that is useful

Comment: 3) Just generally speaking if you want something calculated that will take execution time and with aws lambda it's something you need to pay for. Promises or callbacks or async/await are all the same underneath you won't save precious pennies by using one syntax or another.

Comment: @LevKuznetsov Thanks for your response. Other than the try/catch being not used correctly, is returning a promise the best way to return a value from a callback?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact purpose of [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

> Takes a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e. taking a `(err, value) => ...` callback as the last argument, and returns a version that returns promises.

Your code becomes -

```
const client =
  new SomeClient()

exports.handler = async (event, context) =>
{ const get = util.promisify(client.get.bind(client))
  return await get()
}
```

Which is the same as -

```
const client =
  new SomeClient()

exports.handler = (event, context) =>
  util.promisify(client.get.bind(client))()
```

In the code you provided, you're not using `event` or `context` arguments -

```
const client =
  new SomeClient()

exports.handler = _ =>
  util.promisify(client.get.bind(client))()
```

So you could even shorten this more, if you wanted -

```
const client =
  new SomeClient()

exports.handler =
  util.promisify(client.get.bind(client))
```